# infinite javascript while loop to query table

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

On the markup below - the while loop works when the page is refreshed i.e (postback) - i.e the call in the while loop is functioning.
However it is not updated without a refresh (i.e if i update a value in my database i don't see the change on the webpage). I want it to constantly get the data.

Why not and what is the fix?

**MARKUP**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>TestPage</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/data-import.js"></script>
<script src="js/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="js/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.dateFormat-1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
        </div>
                <div id="tabContent">
                    <div id="fileRepositoryTable">
                        <h2 id="dataImportHeader">File Management</h2>
                        <table width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div id="fileRepository">
                                        <script type="text/template" id="fileRepository-template">
                                                <div id="fileRepositoryTable">

                    <h2 id="dataImportHeader">File Management</h2>
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div id="fileRepository">
                                    <script type="text/template" id="fileRepository-template">
                        <table id = "fileRepositoryTable">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>File Name</th>
                                    <th>Progress</th>
                                    <th>Time Imported</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        <tbody>

                        </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </script>
                        <script type="text/template" id="fileRepositoryrow-template">
                        <td><%= get('fileName')%></td>
                        <td><%= get('progress') +" %"%></td>
                        <td><%= $.format.date(get('timeImported'), 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss') %></td>
                        </script>
                        </div>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    </div>
```

**Backbone Code **

```
DataImport.FileRepositoryView = Backbone.View.extend({


    el: '#fileRepository',
    template: _.template($('#fileRepository-template').html()),

      initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'appendRow');
        this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);
      },

      appendRow: function (fileRepo) {
        var repositoryView = new DataImport.FileRepositoryRowView({model: fileRepo});
        this.$el.find('tbody').append(repositoryView.render().el);
        return this;
      },

      render: function () {
        this.$el.html('');
        this.$el.append(this.template(this));
        _(this.collection.models).forEach(this.appendRow, this);
        return this;
      }
});

DataImport.FileRepositoryRowView = Backbone.View.extend({

     tagName: 'tr',
      template: _.template($('#fileRepositoryrow-template').html()),

      initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.render();
      },

      render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model));
        return this;
      }
});

DataImport.FileRepositoryRows = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: DataImport.Row,
    url: DataImport.rootURL + 'path/getFileRepository',

});
```

**Edited to include backbone code **

Comment: In the source above can you explain why you're setting ten to 10 in the while loop. 'while (ten = 10)` versus `while (ten == 10)` ?

Comment: @KernelPanik or `while (true)` for that matter :)

Comment: Please show us the code that uses these templates. And btw, infinite loops are never a good idea…

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
while (true) {}
```

try

```
setInterval(function() {
    // update code here
}, 0);
```

otherwise, as JS is constantly using the CPU, your browser won't update the page.

If you ever have to use

```
while (whatever) {}
```

for an extended period, you should be tempted to use

```
var clock = setInterval(function() {
    // the code to repeat
    if (!whatever) {
        clearInterval(clock);
    }
}, 0);
```

instead so the browser remains responsive.

Comment: so i tried the below code but it still does not work - it updates on page load but never updates again.        <script type="text/template" id="fileRepositoryrow-template">
       setInterval(function() {
       alert("Hello world");
       <td><%= get('fileName')%></td>
       <td><%= get('progress') +" %"%></td>
       <td><%= $.format.date(get('timeImported'), 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss') %></td>
       }, 3000);
       </script>

Comment: @Nedved85 Try taking a look at the JS console (CTRL + SHIFT + J with Chrome, CTRL + SHIFT + K with FF). Are you getting any Exceptions?

Comment: @Powerslave: Notice that this is not a JavaScript code, but a backbone template (string)

Comment: @Bergi Yes, that what I was wondering about. Still, it should either work or be separated as cooperating JS and template. And, well, as it is just a library over JS, I think it should definitely work. Any `Exception`s will show what to adjust in order to fix the issue.

Comment: Hi again - there are no compilation errors in the chrome - i can retrieve updated data from the server only on page refresh still..

Comment: @Nedved85 I think you need to explicitly re-render the template. Something like `DataImport.FileRepositoryView.render()` has to be called within the repeated code. I'm not a BBJS expert by any means, but it definitely seems that updates are fetched and the BBJS is not re-rendering them.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

In my document.ready function:

```
setInterval(function() {
            DataImport.FileRepositoryRowList.fetch();
            }, 10000);
```

Thanks for the help lads.

Comment: Congratz! I'd also suggest implementing a call for which the server returns (for example) 0 or 1 based on whether it has new content since a given moment or not (you send the timestamp of the latest update with the call) so you can save network bandwidth (and some CPU load) by only fetching all the data when it does make sense.